# Convergence of the series: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2(\ln n)^2\left | \sin(n\pi\sqrt{2}) \right |}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2(\ln n)^2\left | \sin(n\pi\sqrt{2}) \right |}$ converge or diverge?

Could you give me some hints? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Where did you get this question from ?

Comment: 1/n^2 clearly converges. the ln^2 in the denominator only increase the deominator (for all arbitrarily large n). Thus the only issue is what your sin function will do to the series. This may not be sufficient, but you can bound it away from 0 because the argument is never 0 or pi.

Comment: @Alephnull What do you mean "bound it away from $0$"

Comment: @zhw Not only is it never 0 but it never gets arbitrarily close to 0. That is for all n,   0<k<|sin(n pi rt 2)

Comment: @Alephnull But that's false, as $n\pi \sqrt 2$ is equidistributed mod $\pi.$.

Comment: @zhw So rt2 pi n gets arbitrarily close to pi k ? That is rt2 *n becomes arbitrarily close to an integer?

Comment: @Alephnull: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem

Answer (score 8):

Easier than it looks. Let $m$ be the closest integer to $n \sqrt 2.$ We have
$$  | 2 n^2 - m^2 | \geq 1. $$ 
they are integers and $\sqrt 2$ is irrational. $2 n^2 - m^2 \neq 0$ is an integer.

$$  | n \pi \sqrt 2 - m \pi  | = \left| \frac{\pi (2 n^2 - m^2)}{n \sqrt 2 + m} \right| \geq  \frac{\pi }{n \sqrt 2 + m} > \frac{\pi}{3n\sqrt 2} > \frac{1}{2n}  $$
This is as $n$ gets large... Therefore
$$ \left| \sin \left(n \pi \sqrt 2 \right) \right| > \frac{1}{3n} $$
and the thing you are summing is smaller than
$$ 3 \; \; \left( \frac{1}{n \log^2 n} \right) $$
which sum converges by the integral test

Comment: Will; +1 ... Nicely developed.  -Mark